# Animation enter and out of a Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to achieve the animation of entering and leaving the screen, for instance if I have an image centered on the screen and then at the bottom two buttons, I'd like to make an animation when entering the Activity the image comes from up to down until the center of the screen and the buttons from bottom to their position and when tapping "Continue" I want the exact thing, leaving from its current position to up and then appearing the new ones from their respective places.

I've been reading about [`AnimatedContentScope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/AnimatedContentScope#slideIntoContainer(androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection,androidx.compose.animation.core.FiniteAnimationSpec,kotlin.Function1)) and I'm not sure if that's the thing I'm looking for, is there any other function in `Compose` to do so? And if I finally don't want to do the up and down make it easier to change it with another animation.

This is the post [customizing-animatedcontent-in-jetpack-compose](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-animatedcontent-in-jetpack-compose-629c67b45894) I've found.

Comment: I think the official documentation shouid be good to get you started, with a lot of examples: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedcontent